# How to test a method with timeout after calling another method in sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, settimeout, sinon

How can I test a property inside a timeout from another called method?

I want to test a property if it's changed inside the `setTimeout` but using sinons `useFakeTimer` doesn't seems to work. Or am I missing something?

To illustrate here's my code

```
const fs = require('fs');

function Afunc (context) {
    this.test = context;
}

module.exports = Afunc;

Afunc.prototype.start = function () {
    const self = this;

    this.readFile(function  (error, content) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.test = 'changed';
            self.start();
        }, 1000);
    });
}

Afunc.prototype.readFile = function (callback) {
    fs.readFile('./file', function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error);
        }

        callback(null, content);
    })
}
```

And here's what I have so far.

```
describe('Afunc', function () {
    let sandbox, clock, afunc;

    before(function () {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();

        afunc = new Afunc('test');

        sandbox.stub(afunc, 'readFile').yieldsAsync(null);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        clock.restore();
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should change test to `changed`', function () {
        afunc.start();

        clock.tick(1000);

        afunc.test.should.be.equal('changed');

    });
});
```

after the `clock.tick` check the property test is not changed.

Any help is deeply appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
sandbox.stub(afunc, 'readFile').yieldsAsync(null);
```

...to this:

```
sandbox.stub(afunc, 'readFile').yields();
```

...and it should work.

---

**Details**

`yieldsAsync` defers using `process.nextTick` so the callback passed to `readFile` wasn't getting called until "all instructions in the current call stack are processed"...which in this case was your test function.

So the callback that changed `afunc.test` to `'changed'` was getting called...but not until after your test completed.

Comment: You're a life saver man! you deserve a fresh cold beer! Big thanks!

Comment: @per.eight  glad I could help :)